# Mask values on mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a column with values like this:

> 01709100011

I need to transform it to:

> 017.091.0001-1

The values have always the same characters number.

Both columns are varchar

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the current datatype? Are you wanting to convert a int to char or is already char but happens to contain all numbers?

Comment: its varchar for the current and i'll keep that for the "transformed" values

Comment: Does this have to be done in mySQL, can't you do this in the frontend instead?

Comment: @Pekka I have something around 100.000 registries and I think it will be faster directly on MySQL instead of PHP, but if it is hard on MySQL, I'll do it with PHP, its more about learning new techniques =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(test, 1,3),'.',SUBSTRING(test,4,3),'.',SUBSTRING(test,7,4),'-',SUBSTRING(test,11,1)) FROM test;
```

In the above example I used the table test and values in column test.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT CONCAT_WS( "-", CONCAT_WS( ".", SUBSTRING( foo, 0, 3 ), SUBSTRING( foo, 3, 3 ), SUBSTRING( 6, 4 )), SUBSTRING( foo, 10 , 1 )) FROM bar WHERE 1=1;`